# How to select following siblings before the particular following sibling

Tags: xslt

I worked on this. but, still, i am having some problem to achieve this. Here is my input
[code]

```
    <contenu1>
    <intertitre niveau="1">1 Construire sans permis : infraction intentionnelle ou purement « matérielle » ?</intertitre>
    <p>Le nouveau code pénal stipule qu’il.<br/></p>
    <p>Le nouveau code pénal stipule qu’il.<br/></p>
    <p>Le nouveau code pénal stipule qu’il.<br/></p>
    <intertitre niveau="1">2 Quelles sont les principales infractions d’urbanisme ?</intertitre>
    <p>La plupart des infractions urbanistiques sont des délits. Pour les délits les plus graves, des peines de dix ans d’emprisonnement peuvent être prononcées.<br/></p>
    <p>La plupart des infractions urbanistiques sont des délits. Pour les délits les plus graves, des peines de dix ans d’emprisonnement peuvent être prononcées.<br/></p>
    <p>La plupart des infractions urbanistiques sont des délits. Pour les délits les plus graves, des peines de dix ans d’emprisonnement peuvent être prononcées.<br/></p>
    <p>La plupart des infractions urbanistiques sont des délits. Pour les délits les plus graves, des peines de dix ans d’emprisonnement peuvent être prononcées.<br/></p>
    <intertitre niveau="1">3 Comment est établie la constatation des infractions ?</intertitre>
    <p>La constatation des infractions aux règles d’urbanisme, figurant sous le livre IV du code de.<br/></p>
    <intertitre niveau="1">4 Quelles mesures urgentes les autorités peuvent-elles actionner avant la saisine du juge ?</intertitre>
    <p>La constatation des infractions aux règles d’urbanisme, figurant sous le livre IV du code.<br/></p>
    </contenu1>
```

[/code]

And, My expected output is
[code]

```
<d1commdo>
<tit><al>1 Construire sans permis : infraction intentionnelle ou purement « matérielle » ?</al></tit>
<p>Le nouveau code pénal stipule qu’il.<br/></p>
<p>Le nouveau code pénal stipule qu’il.<br/></p>
<p>Le nouveau code pénal stipule qu’il.<br/></p></d1commdo>
<d1commdo>
<tit><al>2 Quelles sont les principales infractions d’urbanisme ?</al></tit>
<p>La plupart des infractions urbanistiques sont des délits. Pour les délits les plus graves, des peines de dix ans d’emprisonnement peuvent être prononcées.<br/></p>
<p>La plupart des infractions urbanistiques sont des délits. Pour les délits les plus graves, des peines de dix ans d’emprisonnement peuvent être prononcées.<br/></p>
<p>La plupart des infractions urbanistiques sont des délits. Pour les délits les plus graves, des peines de dix ans d’emprisonnement peuvent être prononcées.<br/></p>
<p>La plupart des infractions urbanistiques sont des délits. Pour les délits les plus graves, des peines de dix ans d’emprisonnement peuvent être prononcées.<br/></p>
</d1commdo>
<d1commdo>
<tit><al>3 Comment est établie la constatation des infractions ?</al></tit>
<p>La constatation des infractions aux règles d’urbanisme, figurant sous le livre IV du code de.<br/></p></d1commdo>
<d1commdo>
<tit><al>4 Quelles mesures urgentes les autorités peuvent-elles actionner avant la saisine du juge ?</al></tit>
<p>La constatation des infractions aux règles d’urbanisme, figurant sous le livre IV du code.<br/></p>
</d1commdo>
```

[/code]

Could someone please help me to achieve this on XSLT? I need the xslt piece of code.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?  It's easy in 2.0 using `xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with="intertitre"`, but a bit more involved in 1.0.

Comment: Can you describe the kind of transformation you're trying to achieve? We can try to infer it from your sample input/output, but that's error-prone. Also, what XSLT code have you tried already, and how does its output fail to conform to the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, for your new requirements the solution is not trivial but here you have it

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <t>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="intertitre"/>
    </t>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="intertitre">
    <xsl:variable name="nextIntertitrePosition" 
      select="count(following-sibling::intertitre[1]/preceding-sibling::*)"/>
    <d1commdo">
      <tit>
        <a1>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </a1>
      </tit>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::p[
        count(preceding-sibling::*) &lt; $nextIntertitrePosition 
        or 0 = $nextIntertitrePosition]"/>
    </d1commdo>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Edit: some formating done and some minor mistakes removed

Comment: Hi, Kindly explain what is happening actually here "following-sibling::p[count(preceding-sibling::*) &lt; $nextIntertitrePosition or 0 = $nextIntertitrePosition]".   I could not make it exactly how it works. Please.

Comment: @Sakthivel, it selects all p elements after current Intertrite but only ones for which the condition count(preceding-sibling::*) &lt; $nextIntertitrePosition or 0 = $nextIntertitrePosition is true.
The first part of condition is true for all p elements which has less preceding-siblings and the next Intertitre. The second part (0 = $nextIntertitrePosition) is need for when there is no next Intertitre.

Answer (score 2):

This XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <t>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="intertitre"/>
    </t>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="intertitre">
    <d1commdo>
      <tit>
        <a1>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </a1>
      </tit>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::p[1]"/>
    </d1commdo>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...,when applied to your source XML, produces the expected output (wrapped in a top-level element to be well-formed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<t>
  <d1commdo>
    <tit>
      <al>1 Construire sans permis : infraction intentionnelle ou purement « matérielle » ?</al>
    </tit>
    <p>Le nouveau code pénal stipule qu’il.<br/>
    </p>
  </d1commdo>
  <d1commdo>
    <tit>
      <al>2 Quelles sont les principales infractions d’urbanisme ?</al>
    </tit>
    <p>La plupart des infractions urbanistiques sont des délits. Pour les délits les plus graves, des peines de dix ans d’emprisonnement peuvent être prononcées.<br/>
    </p>
  </d1commdo>
  <d1commdo>
    <tit>
      <al>3 Comment est établie la constatation des infractions ?</al>
    </tit>
    <p>La constatation des infractions aux règles d’urbanisme, figurant sous le livre IV du code de.<br/>
    </p>
  </d1commdo>
  <d1commdo>
    <tit>
      <al>4 Quelles mesures urgentes les autorités peuvent-elles actionner avant la saisine du juge ?</al>
    </tit>
    <p>La constatation des infractions aux règles d’urbanisme, figurant sous le livre IV du code.<br/>
    </p>
  </d1commdo>
</t>
```

Comment: Hi, But, on the input file, i may have multiple paragraphs[<p>]. I think, this code will work on that. Could you let me know on that?

Comment: I think, this your piece of code will not work on the above input? Could you please give me an idea?

Comment: According you expected result example it works, but according to you title no. It seems your title is not coherent with the result expected example.

Comment: Hi, Now, I change the expected output format. Could you please help to achieve this output from the above input? It would be more helpful